# PyQt: How to draw a line to connect 2 different QSvgWidgets together?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, drawing

Just now, I have created a svgWidget class for drag&drop in the centralWidget and each svgWidget is able to create a contextMenu by right-click.

What I want to do is by choosing "Connect" in the contextMenu, I can draw a line from that svgWidget to another svgWidget I click afterward. Also, when I drag one of the svgWidget after the line is drawn, the line between them is still connected.

I have tried to create a class but it has never triggered paintEvent.

```
class CConnectionLine(QWidget):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.startPoint = QPoint()
        self.endPoint = QPoint()
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        self.startPoint = e.pos()
        self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.endPoint = e.pos()
            self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, e) -> None:
        if self.startPoint.isNull() != False & self.endPoint.isNull() != False:
            q = QPainter(self)
            q.drawLine(self.startPoint, self.endPoint)
            self.startPoint.setX(0)
            self.startPoint.setY(0)
            self.endPoint.setX(0)
            self.endPoint.setY(0)
            self.drawing = False
        else:
            event.ignore()
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Also note that if you're trying to get "free" positions that allow arbitrary movement of objects that will keep "connections" between them, using QWidget is probably not the best choice, and you should consider the [Graphics View framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) instead.